# Simple jQuery animation: position change not occuring as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm new to jQuery, and have written a very simple script using the `.animate()` function. Here's the complete HTML source code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing jQuery</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            div {
                width: 400px;
                height: 300px;
                position: relative;
                left: 10px;
                margin: 10px 20px;
            }
            #red {
                background-color: red;
            }
            #green {
                background-color: green;
            }
            #blue {
                background-color: blue;
            }

        </style>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("div").click(function() {
                    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.6, left: "+=40;"}, 2000);   
                });


            });
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
        <div id="blue"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It appears that writing the `.animate()` function this way only animates the opacity of the clicked `div` and does not affect any change in its position. Interestingly, if I reverse the order of the arguments in the `.animate()` function, as so:

```
$("div").click(function() {
                    $(this).animate({left: "+=40",opacity: 0.6}, 2000); 
                });
```

There occurs both a change in position and a change in opacity. I followed the syntax from the `.animate()` [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), and there's a similar syntax used there:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in my code itself, just can't put my finger on it yet.

Comment: You have a `;` in the `left` property value (first code, on the `$(this).animate` line)

Comment: Ah! Dang it. Confused with css syntax again. Thanks!